# gzip file with splitting the record into columns when the one of the column value in double quote

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have gzip file which contains columns separated by comma, but when the column value is within double quotes the commas should be kept as it is. I wrote the following code:

```
                           input = gzip.open(file, "rb")
                            reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
                            input_file = reader(input)
                            try:
                                count = 0
                                for line in input_file:

                                    try:
                                        # print 'count='
                                        # print count
                                        if len(line) != 0:

                                            col = line.split(',')
```

My data in the file looks like:

```
4798151,1137351,nam_p0,2762913,nam_r000,"NAM_Rack, Power & Cooling",3
4798151,1135623,nam_s0,2762914,nam_a0,"NAM_Advise, Transform & Manage",3
```

When I was splitting  data with comman, the comma with in double quotes should ignore and come into a column. I am not sure how to add the condition treating the text enclosed in double quote as one. A quick response would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: You might have more luck using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read your file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

**Demo**

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> line = '4798151,1137351,nam_p0,2762913,nam_r000,"NAM_Rack, Power & Cooling",3'
>>> handler = StringIO.StringIO(line)
>>> [row for row in csv.reader(handler, delimiter=',')]
[['4798151', '1137351', 'nam_p0', '2762913', 'nam_r000', 'NAM_Rack, Power & Cooling', '3']]
```

In this case you can use this *direct approach*:

```
with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as handler:
    for row in csv.reader(handler, delimiter=","):
        # row processing HERE
```

Comment: in this case, I have a problem in reading UTF-8 characters. please advise.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve this issue using unicodecsv package.